# Karate: JS function doesn't work when test runs in docker container

Tags: karate

I'm having some problems with running tests in docker. I'm not sure if this is Karate thing or docker configuration.

Background looks like this:

```
  Background:
    * configure report = { showLog: true, showAllSteps: false }
    * def ts = call read('classpath:utilities/helper-random-data-js.feature@timestamp')
    * def timestamp = ts.timestamp
    * print "Current timestamp " + timestamp
```

JS located in helper-random-data-js.feature@timestamp

```
  @timestamp
  Scenario: Generate timestamp
    * def getDate =
    """
    function() {
    var unix = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000)
    return unix;
    }
    """
    * def timestamp = getDate()
    * print timestamp
```

Everything works as expected when I'm running tests on local env via command line

```
xx - scenario called at line: 4 by tag: @timestamp
xx - [print] 1614103214
xx - [print] Current timestamp 1614103214
```

Problem starts when I'm running docker container with this test:

docker run karate_docker mvn test -DargLine="-Dkarate.env=stage" -Dtest=E2eRunner -Dkarate.options="--tags @test1"

```
xx - scenario called at line: 4 by tag: @timestamp
xx - [print] 1.614103807E9
xx - [print] Current timestamp 1614103807
```

As a result, the test fails because incorrect timestamp

```
  @test1
  Scenario: xxx
    Given url my_url
    And path 'billing/history/' + user_id
    And param startDate = timestamp
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

Result:
https://xx/billing/history/0000?startDate=1.614103807E9

Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app
COPY ./src/test/java /usr/src/app/src/test/java


RUN mvn -B -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml -s /usr/share/maven/ref/settings-docker.xml prepare-package -DskipTests
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: sorry, too much for me to diagnose, so follow this process if you can: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also see if the new version helps: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide

Comment: well, I updated to 0.9.9.RC4 and it works :) JS function works without any issues, so solution was super simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed if you upgrade to the 1.0 series / RC version.

Please find more details here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide